# how to fix CSRF token not found on console

Tags: laravel

How to fix CSRF token not found on laravel 5.4, i try to learn vue js in laravel but i have error in my console "CSRF token not found", help me how to fix this error.

[image]

Comment: You should paste error logs or elaborate a little more on what the issue is. But definitely post errors or code. The more errors you post the better feedback you will get.

Comment: This also happens if you happen to dump($someVar) before the actual headers.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can add the following meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Vue, here's the way to go:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = Laravel.csrfToken;
next();
});
```

or

```
<script>
window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
    'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
]); ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

> 1) Where this error come from ?

This error come from **resources/js/bootstrap.js**

> 2) Why this error occured ?

see below snippet , it is try to find out meta tag of name csrf-token ,
 if token found then add as headers to axios http library.else show error

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

> 3) What is the Solution ?

**VerifyCsrfToken** middleware will check for the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request header.

You could store the token in an HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

It will generate token as shown in Image :

[image]

For Ajax Request :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

For VueJS 2.0 :

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
```

read more about CSRF token : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer bro! Sometimes it's better to explain what's the problem and the solution rather than just leaving a line of code without explanation even it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using

`let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');`

Try using

`let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');`

Basically your script is unable to read meta tag with csrf-token, in that case, this should work.

Comment: I dont understand why this solves the issue, but it does. Thank you

Comment: This fixes my issue as well, why is that? The <meta> tag is located in the head.

Answer (score 0):

What could be a problem as well is if you're ending a `@section` with a semicolumn. Like what happened with me I was doing

`@endsection;`

Which caused the error. When I changed it to

`@endsection`

The error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

Or Else You can simply pass the URl in **$except** array, to exclude that URL from CSRF verification.

File

```
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

Like this

```
 protected $except = [
        "readPDF/*",
    ];
```

This solution only applies when particular URL is need to be excluded from csrf verification so use it carefully guys.

Answer (score -2):

In your `bootstrap.js` file replace this line `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');` by `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');`

It would be

```
let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x- 
    csrf-token');
}
```

This also solves the post-axios requests when you have forms in a vue component.